# How do I delete Google Managed Certs from the Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

1. I have old and unused Google Managed Certificates on HTTPS Load Balancer.
2. I want to delete them since we are limited to 15 and I think old certs may be  causing problems with browser clients.
3. How do I delete old certs from the console? I don't want to install google command line software on my workstation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> In the left panel of the Edit HTTP(S) load balancer page, click Frontend configuration.
>   In the right panel, click the X next to the certificate resource you want to delete.
>   Click Done.

Full article: 
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#delete-ssl-cert-resource

Comment: This answer is correct. To add, the certificate cannot be assigned to a service if you want to delete it.

Comment: I don't see what you're describing?

Comment: They probably changed a lot since then. It's been a while. Try going under Network services > Load Balancing, then click Advanced menu option to get the Certificates tab.

Comment: Something installed this and is causing bad performance... Trying to use port 6443 100 times per minute... I already managed my own certificates via cert-manager